# How to write a package in Python with modules that reference each other?

Tags: python, import, module, python-module, python-packaging

I am trying to make a package with modules inside that import each other and I'm very confused on how it works. I made three files: `test1.py`, `test2.py` and `__init__.py` which are contained in my package directory `testpack`.
The contents of the files are as follows:

```
# test1.py

def demo():
    print("123")
    return
```

```
# test2.py
import test1

def demo2():
    print("test 2")
    test1.demo()

if __name__=="__main__":
    demo2()
```

The `__init__.py` file is left empty. When I run `test2.py` on it's own I get the expected output:

```
    test 2
    123
```

I also have a `main.py` file in the parent directory of `testpack`

```
# main.py 

import testpack.test1
import testpack.test2

testpack.test2.demo2()
```

Running this gives the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:/packages/main.py", line 2, in <module>
        import testpack.test2
      File "E:\packages\testpack\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
        import test1
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test1'
```

Following some tips I tried running a different version of the code which yielded the same results:

```
# main.py alternative

from testpack.test2 import demo2

demo2()
```

What am I missing? My logic was that when importing `testpack.test2` Python goes into `test2.py` where it has to import `test1`. Importing `test1` shouldn't be an issue because we can successfully run `test2.py` on it's own, so it would construct `demo2()` using the function from `test1`, and I'd be all done, but I'm obviously wrong. At one point I thought that running `import testpack.test1` before `import testpack.test2` could be posing problems because I'd be importing `test1` twice (once inside `test2` also), but with the alternate version of `main` not running as well I'm completely lost.

**SOLVED:** As per MisterMiyagi's suggestion, the solution was to use  `from . import test1` instead of `import test1` in `test2.py`. The dot specifies that the file to be imported is located in the same directory as the current file, a double dot would specify that the file to be imported is located in the parent directory, etc. I found this article to be helpful https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

Comment: ``import .test1`` etc.

Comment: The above comment is referring to the `test2.py` file